# Setup default date format like yyyy-mm-dd in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

A simple & short question:

How can I setup a **default** date format in powershell like yyyy-mm-dd ? so any date output will be like this format?

or How to setup a date format **globally** in one script ?

Is there a way to output date only without time? when I output LastWriteTime, Default is

`13-03-2014 14:51`

I only need `13-03-2014` but `14:51`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A date in PowerShell is a `DateTime` object. If you want a date string in a particular format, you can use the built-in string formatting.

```
PS C:\> $date = Get-Date
PS C:\> $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
2014-04-02
```

You can also use the string format (`-f`) operator:

```
PS C:\> "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f $date
2014-04-02
```

The `LastWriteTime` property of a file is a `DateTime` object also, and you can use string formatting to output a string representation of the date any way you want.

You want to do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse \\path\ -filter *.pdf | Select-Object LastWriteTime,Directory
```

You can use a calculated property:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Documents -filter *.pdf -Recurse |
  Select-Object Directory, Name, @{Name="LastWriteTime";
  Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")}}
```

Run

```
help Select-Object -Full
```

and read about calculated properties for more information.

Comment: Here is what I need to do:  `gci -recu \\path\ -filter *.pdf | select LastWriteTime,Directory | export-csv \\path\000.csv`  how can I setup a $date in this?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, very useful, I will read the `help` for some basic concept.

Comment: This is ok, but I don't want to modify every line of date code to avoid the (weird, foreign, and confusing) US date format.  Why PS doesn't default to the Windows date format is a bit beyond me.

Comment: Why would you need to modify every line of date code? (Remember, a `DateTime` is an object, not a string representation of a date/time.)

Answer (score 17):

i've used this, it works for me, just copy it at the beginning of your script

```
$currentThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread
$culture = [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture.Clone()
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$currentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
$currentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
```

in case you'll find problem in loading assembly for CultureInfo (i had this issue on Windows 2008 Server), change line 2 in this way

```
$currentThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread
$culture = $CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone()
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'dd-MM-yyyy'
$currentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
$currentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
```

Comment: Thank you - worked for me! I have used `LongDatePattern`.

Comment: This is more useful than having to use .ToString on every output line

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 14):

for always usage you can add in your .\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1

```
$culture = (Get-Culture).Clone()
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
Set-Culture $culture
```

Comment: This is great for setting the format for all of your powershell sessions. This way you don't have to do it for each script or command and other users can still use their own format.

Comment: That's the best answer based on how the question has been written. I faced similar case that on my local computer I develop an azure function app which handling date format (key of my hashtable), but when i push in Azure it doesn't work because the function (Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail) retrieves the date in US format on the function app, i will force the Culture on the function app, so i will be sure to het the date format as on my local computer.

Comment: I don't have this file on my computer, so I believe that the default date/time format is retrieved from somewhere else and can be overwritten by values in this particular PS1 file. Do you know where the default date/time format is written? Or is retrieved from some regional setting or so? (I'm working with Windows 10)