# how to format one column of an object in the pipeline

Tags: powershell

I have an object in PowerShell that I'm trying to push to a plain text file.  It works great except for the format of the date column.  I want it to be "20200604" instead of "6/4/2020 12:00AM".  I've found a number of methods to format dates, but none appear to work as part of a select-object command.

How do I make this work?  Code snippet below.

```
Import-Excel -Path $file.FileName -AsDate "OrderDate" '
 | Select-Object "OrderDate" '
 | convertto-csv -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out.  Special thanks to @Bill_Stewart for his post a long time ago that I just found.

| Select-Object @{Name="OrderDate"; Expression={$_."OrderDate".ToString("yyMMdd")}}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826185/setup-default-date-format-like-yyyy-mm-dd-in-powershell

Comment: you can post the Answer to your Question and mark it as accepted. it won't gain you much in reputation, but it will make the answer easier to others to read. [*grin*]