# How to change Get-Date commandlet default result value in Powershell

Tags: powershell, types, console

**Get-Date** returns something like "*26 July 2023 12:54:21*"

this is the **default** representation
(it is the content of property .*DateTime* which is a string)


how can I set the default result of Get-Date to .Year (for example)

- This is a generic types question but I think is better to put it this way
- Update-TypeData did not solve this problem... just for Format-List/Table/Wide...
- I know I can do (get-date).year... that is not the point!

Comment: Get-Date returns a DataTime object which is a number (not a string).  When displaying the string you can display in any format.  So you can use $date = Get-Date "1/1/2023".  The convert to string $date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").  The DateTime format are here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33647794

Comment: Like stated above (Get-Date).DateTime is a string... as you can inspect with (Get-date).DateTime.GetType()... an also as stated above the objective is to change the DEFAULT RESULT of Get-Date...

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for is to `Update-FormatData`. You want to change how the default view of a `DateTime` instance looks like when outputted ?

Comment: I want to change how the default view of a DateTime ( as an example,,, my intent is to generalize to other types/commandlets)... but I don't want to mess with .psxml files... something should exist like a "Set-FormatData"... or included in the "Update-FormatData"... as the current "Update-FormatData" do not have this capacity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- This answer addresses how to change the representation of `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime))  instances (such as output by [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date)) *when converted to strings*, either explicitly or implicitly.
- This has no impact on using `[datetime]` instances *as themselves*.

---

You can use **[`Update-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata)** to both modify the **`.DateTime`** `ScriptProperty` ETS ([Extended Type System](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) property of `[datetime]` instances and to override the type-native **`.ToString()`** method with a `ScriptMethod` ETS property, but there's a wrinkle:

- Due to a **bug**, present up to at least PowerShell 7.3.9 (current as of this writing), in the context of `[string]` *casts* and PowerShell's *string interpolation* (inside [expandable (double-quoted) strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)) an ETS `.ToString()` method is unexpectedly *not* honored - see [GitHub issue #14561](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14561); sadly, it appears that this [bug *won't get fixed*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14561#issuecomment-1043675075).

```bash
# Override .ToString()
Update-TypeData -Force -TypeName System.DateTime -MemberType ScriptMethod -MemberName ToString -Value {
  [string] $this.Year
}
# Redefine .DateTime
Update-TypeData -Force -TypeName System.DateTime -MemberType ScriptProperty -MemberName DateTime -Value {
  $this.ToString() # This calls the overridden .ToString() method.
}
```

Now, the `.DateTime` property of `[datetime]` instances reports just the instance's year, and so do (explicit and implicit) `.ToString()` calls:

```bash
# === These work:
# Use of the redefined .DateTime via the formatting system.
Get-Date
[datetime]::Now
# Use of the overridden .ToString() method.
(Get-Date).ToString()
Write-Host (Get-Date) # implicit .ToString() call 
[pscustomobject] @{ Date = (Get-Date) } # implicit .ToString() call on nested values

# === Due to the BUG mentioned above, the following do NOT work.
# They use the original .ToString() format.
"$(Get-Date)"
[string] (Get-Date)
```

Comment: Yes... "this is the way" (Mando dixit ;-)... did not occurred me to override .toString()... and if you add ( $this.ToString( "yyyy" ) ) you can simplify overriding only the ScriptProperty and use only one sentence...

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ZEE; note that if you only override `.DateTime`, the following cases won't work: `(Get-Date).ToString()`, `Write-Host (Get-Date)`, and `[pscustomobject] @{ Date = (Get-Date) }`

Comment: Yep... only overriding .toString ( not messing with .DateTime ) only affects the result sent to the console... keeping rest of the stuff working... seems to a good solution for the problem...

Comment: @ZEE, understood, but to be clear: unless you override `.DateTime` also, something like `Get-Date` or `[datetime]::Now` will use the original formatting, because the formatting data associated with `[datetime]` uses that property in lieu of `.ToString()` (the property has conditional logic built in, in conjunction with `Get-Date`'s `-DisplayHint` parameter) - though perhaps that's what you want. Neither the original `.DateType` property (an ETS `ScriptProperty`) nor any later redefinition would interfere with how `[datetime]` instances work.