# powershell, ToString() script methods aren't honored in variable expansion

Tags: powershell

I'm trying without success to change `[hashtable]`'s `ToString()` function to be able have a human-readable thing when using variable expansion in string. here's what I did:

```
function customToString { 'I am Groot' }

$hash = @{ foo = 'bar' }

$hash | Add-Member -MemberType scriptmethod -Name ToString -Value $function:customToString -Force

$hash.ToString()
$hash -as [string]
"$hash"
'{0}' -f $hash
```

I get my custom output **only** when I explicitly call `ToString()`. in all other cases I get `System.Collections.Hashtable`. I also tried to update the base class with

```
Update-TypeData -TypeName System.Collections.HashTable -MemberType scriptmethod -MemberName ToString -Value $function:customToString
```

with the same result.

the next step would be to try to subclass `[hashtable]` and override `ToString()` there but I was not able to have a running class yet.

is the fact that my custom `ToString()` is not honored a bug or do I miss something obvious?

### edit 1

even better ! if I put `$hash` into an array variable, eg. `$array=,$hash`, `"$array"` will use the custom `ToString()` but neither `'{0}' -f $array` nor `$array -as [string]` will.

and the variable seems mandatory as `"$(,$hash)"` will not use it either.

### edit 2

OK, this is a plain bug that apparently won't be fixed in a foreseeable future - check link in the first comment by @zett42.

meanwhile, I finally coined a subclass-ing way of getting around the bug. I post it, in case it may help someone in the future.

### workaround

```
class printableHashtable : hashtable {
    
    hidden static
    [printableHashtable] op_Implicit([hashtable]$hash) {
        $new = [printableHashtable]::new()
        $hash.getEnumerator() | foreach { $new.add($_.key,$_.value) }
        return $new
    }
    
    [string]ToString() { return 'I am Groot' }
}
```

for my current need, print a splatting variable with `Write-Debug`, the new `[printableHashtable]` does the trick. a `[printableHashtable]` variable can directly be used in lieu of a plain `[hashtable]` for splatting and it can easily be printed with `Write-Debug`

casting the `[hashtable]` at print time:

```
$params=@{date='2023/08/25'}
Get-Date @params
Write-Debug ([printableHashtable]$params -as [string])
```

using a `[printableHashtable]` variable for splatting:

```
$params=[printableHashtable]@{date='2023/08/25'}
Get-Date @params
Write-Debug ($params -as [string])
Write-Debug "$params"
```

hope the workaround may help someone.

@moderators: the question is **related** to the *duplicate* but is not the same.  both are due to the same bug in powershell but the questions are different. this question may stay closed, but please remove the *duplicate* thing from the title as this could prevent future readers to find the proposed workaround. have a nice day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Get-Date commandlet default result value in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76771116/how-to-change-get-date-commandlet-default-result-value-in-powershell) -- The answer of @mklement0 explains the known `.ToString()` bug.

Comment: @zett42 unfortunately yes, the bug pointed by mklement0 answers my question: this is a bug. thank for the link.

Comment: @zett42 I edited the question to post a possible workaround. FWIW.

Comment: FWIW, it also seems like you can't Add-Member -Force a ToString method for a PowerShell array object.  It appears I am resigned to making a custom class that extends System.Collections.ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a source for this but it looks like Powershell use its own logic and disregard custom `ToString()` when using a hashtable. One way to make this work though is to use a PSCustomObject instead.

```
# Create a custom object
$person = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = "Groot"
    Age  = 4
    Quote = 'I am Groot'
}

Add-Member -InputObject $person -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name ToString -Value {return $this.Quote} -Force
```

Or if you want a hashtable

```
$person = [PSCustomObject]@{
    value = @{
        Name = "Groot"
        Age  = 4
        Quote = 'I am Groot'
    }
  
}
Add-Member -InputObject $person -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name ToString -Value {return $this.Value.Quote } -Force
```

Using this way of doing it, you will get the desired output.

```
# Theses will output "I am Groot"
$person.ToString() 
"$person"
'{0}' -f $person
```

Comment: I love the idea of encapsulating the faulty structure in a [PSCustomObject]. unfortunately it would be a lot of refactoring for my actual need, print a splatting variable with Write-Debug. but I keep it in mind for future use case.

Comment: I edited the question to post a possible workaround. FWIW.